# Reject is not returning the response if the token is invalid - nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, callback, axios

I am calling the function verifyAsset(url) inside verifyUser(). On calling the function verifyAsset(url),the control goes to verifyAsset(url) but when there is error in the response, it goes in the catch block, the console.log's output also gets reflected in the terminal but the reject statement does not gets executed. It does not throw any error and the further statements also do not get executed.

```
const verifyUser = async(req, res, next) => {
    url = <some value>
    auth = <some value>
    await verifyAsset(url, auth);
    next();
   }

const verifyAsset = async(url, auth) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    authorization: auth,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return resolve({ 'Message': 'Success.' });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                return reject({ error: error.response.data.error_description, auth: 'unsuccessful', code: 400 });
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe adding "await" before calling "verifyAsset" could help? `await verifyAsset(url, auth);`

Comment: I tried adding 'await' before 'verifyAsset', still the same issue. I'll make changes in the question for the same.